# Checkout problem after upgrade to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

2 problems on onepage checkout:
1. I have to enter login details twice - 
first time it stays there and blanks the fields when I press the 'Login. button
2. When it does login it takes me to the customers account page and not to the 
next step in checkout.
3. The site is [australianplantsonline.com.au][1]
Please help !!!!!
[1]: http://australianplantsonline.com.au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the form_key hidden field in your template. From what version did you upgrade?

Check your `persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml` file and make sure you have the following line in your login form:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Also check if you have the following code in `core.xml`:

```
<default>
    <block name="formkey" type="core/template" template="core/formkey.phtml" />
</default>
```

---

Post scriptum after speaking with this user:

Other than the `formkey`, the user had a module called `Minerva Checkout` not updated to work with his Magento version.

We fixed replacing line 35 of `app/code/community/Minerva/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

from:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->getRequest()-getRequestUri());
```

to:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_secure' => true)));
```

Hope it helps other people having the same issue.

Comment: I only have a persistent folder in my base and not in my theme.
In that file, I can't see a place to put "getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>" as that usually goes after "<ul class="form-list", but I can't see that in this file.
I'm somewhat inexperienced in this and bludgeoning around in the dark.

Comment: Somebody (not me) upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9.2.3 and left me with a Rocky Horror show. Nothing much worked. Took me all day yesterday to thrash around and get things back up. These seem to be the only issues left.
btw - thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Ok, so the problem is this, they changed it in 1.8. You are probably taking the login form from a template file  that has not been projected for 1.8+ . Try looking for "checkout/onepage/login.phtml" too (without persistent).

Comment: You have to put this code just after the <form> tag open.

Comment: Tried in the persistent - didn't work - will now look for more ...

Comment: Check my last comment, also try on "checkout/onepage/login.phtml".

Comment: Do I need:
<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>

Comment: It has the same effect, but if this way works for you and mine does not, it means you also have to change yout layout.xml file adding the formkey block.

Comment: Can you fix this problem I have? If so,how much do you charge?
My client is getting very distressed>
Can we talk via email? I cannot use chat as I have no credits (new here)

Comment: You can see my contacts in my profile. I will help you for free if you agree to publish the solution here.

Comment: I saw details of your website and Linked In, but not email ??

Comment: Just added: info@riccardotempesta.com

Comment: Of course I will publish the solution. I will still pay you.It's not a problem.

Comment: Email on its way - thx

Comment: Riccardo found the **needle in the haystack**. I would have been stuck forever.This Minerva checkout module seems to no longer exist, and is not compatible with the upgraded magento version, so finding and fixing it was the only way.