# Installed SUPE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2 COD redirects back to cart in onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.8

We have a Magento 1.8.1 store running. We installed SUPE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2 and afterwards the COD payment method in onepage checkout is redirecting back to the cart.
Many customers use COD in our store, so that is a bit of a problem. I tested in all browsers and checked if there is any call in HTTP instead of HTTPS through ajax, but couldn't find anything. Also, nothing in Logfiles.
Interesting to note is that the final payment page shows up, but only for a brief second, then redirects to the cart.
Any ideas what causes the redirect?
Thanks so much, Martin

Comment: Maybe a Javascript redirect?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with the theme needing to be updated and probably needs a formkey

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Exactly where you need it might vary but this site is a good place to start. Search "Formkey"

[Checkout problem after upgrade to 1.9.2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102068/checkout-problem-after-upgrade-to-1-9-2-3)